# SQL Server socket exception in Unity

Tags: sql-server, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server in Unity but it throws an error:

> SocketException: address incompatible with requested protocol
>
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy)
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket+Worker.Connect ()
>   Rethrow as TdsInternalException: Server does not exist or connection refused.
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70..ctor (System.String server, Int32 port, Int32   packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion version)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds80..ctor (System.String server, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionPoolManager.CreateConnection (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionInfo info)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionPool.GetConnection ()
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open ()
>   Rethrow as SqlException: Server does not exist or connection refused.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open ()

My SQL Server connection string (it works in Visual Studio correctly):

```
Data Source=HASAN;Initial Catalog=kinectDb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=12345;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;
```

SQL Server Configuration Manager screenshots:

[image]

[image]

**Note:**  I think this problem is related with SQL Server configuration not unity.

Comment: Check the firewall on the SQL server. Turn off windows firewall and see if it suddenly starts working

Comment: Isnt there anyone to solve my problem ? @marc_s you edited my question but didnt answer.